# The method 'ElevatedButton' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, button

For a simple design I wanted quickly implement a ElevatedButton in a Flutter project but Flutter does not find the ElevatedButton at all. The only thing I find is the ElevatedButtonTheme and if I type in the ElevatedButton manually (incl. the child and onPressed) the name is maked as an error.

[image]

Do I do something wrong? Do I need to include something extra other than the `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';"`

Here the source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
        title: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/logo.png',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 40,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Quest 01 | 2022',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('Example'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error message is:

> lib/pages/landingpage.dart:33:15: Error: The method 'ElevatedButton'
> isn't defined for the class 'LandingPage'.
>
> - 'LandingPage' is from 'package:eumood/pages/landingpage.dart' ('lib/pages/landingpage.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of
>   an existing method, or defining a method named 'ElevatedButton'.
>   ElevatedButton(
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Thanks for you help
Best,
Chris

Comment: could you add your code, instead of screen shot?

Comment: Sometimes its your IDE problem and not flutter. Because may be your IDE is not showing the suggestion. You can copy elevated button code from internet and paste it in your file. If, it's still showing the error then let me know

Comment: @eamirho3ein: I added the source code. I still have the same problem.

Comment: @Chris what is happening when you run this code?

Comment: @eamirho3ein: Sorry i completely forgot to add the error message. I jsut added it. I can't run the code, see the error message.

Comment: what is happening if you run flutter clean and then run your project?

Comment: @eamirho3ein: I did run Flutter clean already, it does not fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out a (quite radical) solution for my problem. I updated my kotlin version and the dependencies. I'm not sure this is the solution or maybe there was something else wrong but at least it did the trick for me.

I changed the parameters in
**[projectname]/android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version)

Answer (score 0):

can you show your imports please
else can you use this example without auto complete

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text('Example'),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without using AutoComplete,

```dart
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: (){}, 
        child: Text("Elevated Button")
               ),
```